# How do I convert words to their equivalent number?

Tags: ruby, nlp, linguistics

If I have a positive integer written as a string, such as `"three"` or `"forty nine"`, is there a simple way to convert this to an integer?

I'm happy using Linguistics to convert the other way, but I've never tried this way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [numbers_in_words](https://github.com/markburns/numbers_in_words) GitHub project. It seems to provide the functionality you are looking for, at least for english number strings.

From the project docs:

```
require 'numbers_in_words'
require 'numbers_in_words/duck_punch'

112.in_words
#=> one hundred and twelve

"Seventy million, five-hundred and fifty six thousand point eight nine three".in_numbers
#=> 70556000.893
```

Comment: I'd find it very difficult to tell my boss with a straight face that I was duck-punching the output.

Comment: That looks like a useful project.

Comment: My face was anything but straight when I discussed this with my boss.